# Do map of pointers is different with common way of using maps

Tags: go

I want to create cache with map. As map doesn't allow reference to its value, so it's not possible to change values in called functions.

After some search, I found, it's possible with creating map of pointer (of struct). It Almost solve problem and can work like variable by reference
But as i found a few using of this method for map. I worry about using it to be safe. 
Is anyone has experience of using map of pointer? and is it right way to use it?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cache struct {
    name    string
    counter int
}

func incr(c Cache) {
    c.counter += 1
}
func incrp(c *Cache) {
    c.counter += 2
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]Cache)
    m["james"] = Cache{name: "James", counter: 10}

    c := m["james"]
    incr(c)
    fmt.Println(c.name, c.counter) // James 10

    mp := make(map[string]*Cache)
    mp["james"] = &Cache{name: "James", counter: 10}
    cp := mp["james"]
    incrp(cp)
    fmt.Println(cp.name, cp.counter) // James 12

}
```

> edited: My text had some confusing words and sentences, that caused to misunderstanding, so i tried to fixed it

Comment: No one can answer that for your application with your data running at idea of "large scale". Just run it, measure it, and see if performance is acceptable, and if not, profile it to find out why.

Comment: I don't want the performance exactly. I want to know is it right way to using this @Adrian

Comment: There is no "right way" as this depends on your workload and nobody can tell you. You have to measure yourself.

Comment: Sure, using pointers is a fine way, and will almost certainly not be a performance problem for you. Just write it, measure, and see.

Comment: thanks @AlexGuerra

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this and still have a `map` of non-pointers, with a *pointer receiver* on the struct:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cache struct {
    name    string
    counter int
}

func (c *Cache) incr() {    // the '(c *Cache)' is the receiver;
    c.counter += 1          // it makes incr() a method, not just a function
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]Cache)
    m["james"] = Cache{name: "James", counter: 10}

    c := m["james"]
    c.incr()
    fmt.Println(c.name, c.counter)
}
```

Output:

```
James 11
```

If *receivers* and *methods* are new to you, here is where they are mentioned in the Tour of Go:  https://tour.golang.org/methods/1

Note the page about *pointer receivers* a few steps later in the Tour:  https://tour.golang.org/methods/4